# Computational cost of indexing and substitution

Tags: c++, matrix

Say I have the following code for **backsubstitution**.

```
for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    double temp = b[i];
    if (i != n - 1) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) 
            temp -= A[i][j] * b[j];
    }
    b[i] = temp/A[i][i];
}
```

But for me as a newbie to programming, the following seems simpler:

```
for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (i != n - 1) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) 
            b[i] -= A[i][j] * b[j];
    }
    b[i] /= A[i][i];
}
```

which requires the indexing of `b[i]` every time it iterates from `j = i+1` to `j = n - 1`. But this `b[i]` is a fixed quantity since this iteration does not depend on the value of `i`.

But I'm not sure which one the complier more prefers. Any help?

Comment: A good optimizer will likely transform the latter into the former, by hoisting `b[i]` computation out of the inner loop. Anyway, if you care about performance, measure it; if you don't measure, this means you don't really care.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes but still: to me OP has a point. It is usually poor style to rely on the optimizer too much, even when one is fairly sure that optimization will work.

Comment: I would not use index ( b[i] ), rather I would use pointers and auto increment ( *p++ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition `double temp = b[i];` encourages the compiler to keep the tally `temp` in one of the CPU's *registers.* With your other code, the compiler might leave the tally in main memory, registers being unsuited to store arrays.

The array would probably be kept in cache unless it were very large, so it would still be fairly fast; but registers are faster.

Comment: It's funny that you should ask this question. I happen to have some hotspot backsubstitution code of my own. It had not occurred to me to pull my tally into a register until you pointed it out. So which of the two of us is actually answering the other's question? I suppose that this has become a collaboration between the two of us, hasn't it? Now we shall both of us each enjoy faster code.